# Unable to edit storyboards in Xamarin Forms for Windows

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am trying to edit the LaunchScreen.storyboard in my iOS project of my Xamarin Forms solution in Visual Studio (VS) for Windows .  When I double click the storyboard to edit it, I receive the error message as follows:

"The iOS Designer requires an active connection to a Mac server. Please connect to a Mac to enable the designer."

However, I am connected to my Mac build server.
[image]

I have seen some older posts where there are mismatches between the Mac build server and the Windows development box so I checked for updates to Visual Studio on the Mac.  There were some so I installed them.  Then when I re-opened my project in Visual Studio for Windows and tried to connect to the Mac, I receive the error message as follows:

[image]

So I clicked to have Visual Studio correct the miss-match error and now I am back to the same error message saying "Something went wrong".. as shown above.

I have checked for updates to VS on Windows and there are currently no updates.  (I really hate it when Microsoft release incompatible updates like this.. ARG!!!)

***Here are the details for the Windows VS:***

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.8.2
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.8.2+30717.126
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C++ 2019   00435-20050-31374-AA182
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.8.553.28003
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   16.1.0.2052803+84e121f1403378489b842e1797df2f3f5a49ac3c
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.8.553.28003
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.8.553.28003
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.1000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.8.553.28003
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.1000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   3.8.0-5.20567.16+53c5d7d3cf13d88978744a32a27c5f8350a8400a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.6.1000.0
HDInsight Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.1000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   16.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.1000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
Azure Stream Analytics Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 - v2.9.30924.1

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.113+g422d40002e.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Process Editor   1.0
Process Editor for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   16.8.43 (00471f8)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   5.8.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62010.06180
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   16.0.21016.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.8.0-5.20567.16+53c5d7d3cf13d88978744a32a27c5f8350a8400a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)   16.0.30608.117
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)

Visual F# Tools   16.8.0-beta.20507.4+da6be68280c89131cdba2045525b80890401defd
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   16.8.000.255 (d16-8@d002176)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   16.8.0.507 (remotes/origin/d16-8@e87b24884)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   16.8.112 (86385a3)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   11.1.0.17 (d16-8/c0e2b8e)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
Mono: be2226b
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-8@79d9533
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-8@2fb1cbc

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   14.4.1.3 (e30c41de3)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

**Here  are the details for VS on the Mac**
=== Visual Studio Professional 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.8.2 (build 41)
Installation UUID: 7927aa3f-75df-48d3-a901-74299635ff3e
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

```
Package version: 612000107
```

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
Mono 6.12.0.107 (2020-02/a22ed3f094e) (64-bit)
Package version: 612000107

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.8.0-5.20519.18+4c195c3ac1974edcefa76774d7a59a2350ec55fa

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.8.0.6860

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/Sdks
SDK Versions:
5.0.100
3.1.404
3.1.403
3.1.402
3.1.302
3.1.301
3.1.300
3.1.200
3.1.102
3.1.101
3.0.101
3.0.100
2.1.701
2.1.700
2.1.505
2.1.302
2.1.301
2.1.4
2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
5.0.0
3.1.10
3.1.9
3.1.8
3.1.6
3.1.5
3.1.4
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.0.1
3.0.0
2.1.23
2.1.22
2.1.20
2.1.19
2.1.18
2.1.16
2.1.15
2.1.14
2.1.13
2.1.12
2.1.11
2.1.9
2.1.2
2.1.1
2.0.5
2.0.0

=== .NET Core 3.1 SDK ===

SDK: 3.1.404

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.15.68
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.2 (17535)
Build 12B45b

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 7.0.0.15 (Visual Studio Professional)
Hash: 87a1b18d8
Branch: d16-8
Build date: 2020-11-16 21:39:40-0500

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 14.4.1.3 (Visual Studio Professional)
Hash: e30c41de3
Branch: d16-8
Build date: 2020-10-20 22:18:50-0400

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.8.0.507
Hash: e87b24884
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2020-10-29 00:31:38 UTC

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 11.1.0.17 (Visual Studio Professional)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-8/c0e2b8e
Android SDK: /Users/gmceaser/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.2

Build Information:
Mono: be2226b
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-8@79d9533
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-8@2fb1cbc

=== Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===

Java SDK: /Users/gmceaser/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.8.0.32
Hash: 01a7774
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2020-10-13 23:32:30 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.8.0.45
Hash: fc0af5f
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2020-10-13 23:32:54 UTC

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 808020041
Git revision: dba789c00d07d6923cce74016b7e406526d683da
Build date: 2020-11-23 04:40:23-05
Build branch: release-8.8
Xamarin extensions: dba789c00d07d6923cce74016b7e406526d683da

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.16.0
Darwin 20.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.1.0
Sat Oct 31 00:07:11 PDT 2020
root:xnu-7195.50.7~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

**Any assistance would be greatly appreciated:
P.S.  I have never tried to edit a storyboard in VS on windows before so I am not sure if I was ever able to do it but I know according to the documentation I am supposed to be able to do it.**

Comment: Hi, I also meet this in my PC. Although I have installed `14.4.1.3` pkg manually, it doesn't work. Maybe it's an issue for this vesion of visual stuido. You could submit it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and share the link here when you have time. Then I also will follow it up there.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - I reported the problem through the feedback feature of Visual Studio but I don't see the problem in the list of my feedback yet.  As soon as it shows, I will post the link here.

Comment: Here is the link to the defect on MS site  https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/myfeedback?port=1025&fsid=70df53d9-f7f0-4c5e-8d4d-7087ecd4855d&entry=myfeedback

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It seems I forget the feedback only can be seen by owners...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So according to Microsoft here is the solution:

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1255414/view.html for a work around. Basically, disconnect from Mac, Forget Mac, Add mac again via IP Address. Downside is that you get 2 connection options to the same Mac.

As a heads up - you may need to do the forget then reconnect to the Mac when you open a different project you want to edit the storyboard for even if you are already connected to the Mac by IP address.  Basically, if you ever get the error, disconnect from the Mac - forget the Mac then reconnect to it by IP address.